# Crazy battery numbers

Tags: macos, battery, powerpc

I'm getting crazy battery numbers in my ancient (but fully operational) PowerBook G4 2005 running Mac OS X Tiger 10.4.11. The battery is very nearly shot. The numbers reported by coconutBattery also reported by System Profiler.

How can I reset those crazy Maximum Battery Charge and Current Battery Capacity to actual numbers?

I've removed the battery and done a SMC reset with no change.

[image]

Comment: Reinstall the battery monitor program or install another...

Comment: @SolarMike, the same numbers are reported by System Profiler.

Answer (score -1):

I would look for a different app. It may be hard to find one for your system. Several I looked at were for newer system versions than you have. You can try the [Edurance app](https://enduranceapp.com) which supposedly has options to increase battery life or use an increased speed of your mac. The downside is that this app is $20.00.  That's a lot to pay when many apps for battery life are free. They supposedly have a free trial. There was no minimum system given for this app so it may run on 10.4.

There is also a way to determine the number of cycles your battery has used. The [instructions are given here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585). In this link, there are other links to determine the maximum cycles your battery has before it needs a battery replacement. Once you determine how many cycles your battery has you can go to one of the links and see if it includes your model.

Comment: The same numbers are reported by System Profiler.

Comment: that where the 2nd part of my answer comes into play.